# How can a Gradle subproject be configured to use convention plugin from ../buildSrc?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I've followed this document https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins to create a convention plugin based on the precompiled script type plugins. Everything works fine when I run `./gradlew clean build` from the root of the project, but if I step into the `prj1` subproject which uses the convention plugin, the build fails with the following message:

```
Plugin [id: 'java-convention'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```

Project layout:

```
buildSrc/
  build.gradle
  src/main/groovy/java-convention.gradle
prj1/
  build.gradle
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

root level `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-convention'
}
```

root level `settings.gradle`

```
include('prj1')
```

`buildSrc/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
}
```

`buildSrc/src/main/groovy/java-convention.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}
```

`prj1/build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-convention'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

I thought that the presence of a `buildSrc` directory at the root level would cause the plugin jar file that gets built to be automatically added to the class path of the subprojects. As mentioned, build runs successfully if I initiate it from the root, but fails when run from the subproject. Do I need to explicitly add the plugin jar to the buildscript section of the subproject? If so, what is the exact syntax since the jar ends up in the `buildSrc/build/libs/` directory? At one point, I had it explicitly included with `includeBuild('../buildSrc')` from the `prj1/settings.gradle` file, but that yielded an error message saying that `buildSrc` was reserved and couldn't be referenced in `includeBuild()`

Answer (score 0):

for the subproject - the plugins should use prefix

```
plugins {
    id 'myproject.java-convention'
}
```

see full example - https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html

Comment: Actually, that is not required. I took the sample convention plugin code that you referenced, and I successfully removed the `myproject` prefix from the plugins, and the id definition in the subprojects. It worked fine without it.

Answer (score 0):

After double and triple checking the project, comparing it to the sample project that @PrasadU suggested, I was still stumped and couldn't figure out what I had done differently. I ended up unzipping the sample project, and then adding my script plugins and building, and that worked.

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`